# Spark streaming cluster mode in Mesos : java.lang.RuntimeException: Stream jar not found

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming, mesos, checkpoint

## Goal :

Running spark streaming applications in cluster mode on mesos, using hdfs and checkpoints.

## Cluster :

- Mesos cluster with 3 slaves.
- One dispatcher connecting to the
  cluster.
- One external hdfs and all binaries installed on each slaves.

**Versions :**
Mesos 1.2.0
spark 2.0.1
hdfs 2.7

**Application sources :**
application.jar, checkpoints and spark binaries stored on hdfs.

## Context:

Launching an application with these configuration :

- "SPARK_EXECUTOR_URI" : "hdfs://*hdfsHost*/spark.tgz
- "spark.submit.deployMode" : "cluster"
- "spark.master" : "spark://*dispatcherHost*"
- "spark.mesos.coarse" :"true"
- mainClass : "enterprise.com.Class"
- jar : "hdfs://*hdfsHost*/application.jar"

**First launch (no checkpoint data) : working**

- One driver is starting with a new mesos framework ID with the name of the application.
- One task (or more) are running on another or same slave.
- checkpoint has been correctly created in hdfs.

**Second launch (with checkpoint data) : not working**

- One driver is starting with a new mesos framework ID with the name of the application.
- One task (or more) are running on another or same slave.
- In case of the driver does not start on the same slave machine as the stored chekpoint, we get the following exception :

## Error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stream '/jars/application.jar' was not found.
at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.handle(TransportResponseHandler.java:222)
...
```

This error occurs because the Driver that is in charge of exposing application jar to the executors, is trying to expose it from the jar path stored by the checkpoint (loaded from hdfs and stored in mesos workdir path = sandbox) that does not exist in the current node.

```
Downloading resource with Hadoop client from 'hdfs://*hdfsHost*/application.jar' to '/var/lib/mesos/slaves/<ID>/frameworks/<frameworkID>/executors/<driverID>/runs/<runID>/application.jar'
...
INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/var/lib/mesos/slaves/<checkpointedID>/frameworks/<checkpointedFrameworkID>/executors/<checkpointedDriverID>/runs/<runID>/spark/../application.jar at spark://<driverHost>/jars/application.jar with timestamp 1498051933921
```

I'm confused by the behaviour.

## Question

- **A)** Why spark is using a rpc interface to expose application jar to executors when using hdfs, instead of executors are loading directly from source ?
- **B)** Why checkpoints store mesos application framework path and try to recover it ?
- **C)** How to fix this issue and run a streaming application on mesos with hdfs and checkpoint on **multiple** slaves ?